# How to run two loop at the same time

Tags: bash, loops

I am wondering how to run too loops at the same time.  This is kind of like my other question, [How to exit a Subshell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41370092/how-to-exit-a-subshell).  I am trying to have two loops running at the same time, and have them be able to share variables.  I tried using a subshell (which clearly failed), tried backgrounding the first loop and running the second one, which didn't work.  What other options do I have?

Comment: [What are you trying to accomplish with these two loops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I am trying to have one write to a file, and the other one display the file with Zenity.  See the linked question.

Comment: 1. Why do they have to run simultaneously? 2. You said that methods you tried didn't work, but didn't say what about them didn't work.

Comment: I could not pass values between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to put the loops in different scripts and call them independently, such as:

```
nohup /folder/myLoop1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
nohup /folder/myLoop2 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

As for sharing variables, one way to do it would be to store the variable on a temporary file, which then can be accessed by all scripts:

```
echo "$myVar" > /tmp/loopVarHolder
myVar="$(cat /tmp/loopVarHolder)"
```

Finally, you could kill (if you need/want) one loop (say) `myLoop2` when `myLoop1` finishes, by adding the following (or similar) at the end of the scrip `myloop1`:

```
killall myLoop2 > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Note: using `nohup` on the terminal (not on a script) can hold the prompt and create a file `nohup.out` somewhere if you don't use a redirection such as `> /dev/null 2>&1` when invoking it.